# Virtual environment choosing wrong source

Tags: python, django, virtual, environment

I am currently working on a website and app using Django that requires me to use a virtual environment that I have specified. Im working on a Macbook using the latest OS. My problem arises when I use the command source v/bin/activate (this is the path to my virtual environment files.) What happens though is that in my terminal, it recognizes that I am in fact in a virtual environment by having the (v) in the beginning but when I do a command such as which python, it leads me to /usr/local/bin/python rather than the source I specified.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this? I have 2 other group members with the same computers as I and theirs seems to work fine.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Mike.

Comment: You are not using sudo at all?

Comment: That command is not recognized but I think you may be onto something. I'm going to try and disable the need for using sudo and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear, I meant that you should not be using sudo at all ever, not creating a viratualenv, not to install packages etc..

Comment: Holy Moley, I've been using sudo all the time. Perhaps I need to try reinstalling not using sudo commands?

Comment: Yes, a big advantage of a virtualenv is you don't need permissions so you should always create your virtualenvs as a normal user or else strange things will happen!